# Allow Access-Control for Subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having issues setting up a generic Allow Origin for any subdomain in my .htaccess file. The following works for a singular subdomain:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://subdomain.website.com
    </IfModule>
```

But what I am looking for is something similar to this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin {ANY SUBDOMAIN}.website.com
</IfModule>
```

I have tried using a simple `*.website.com` wildcard, but that does not seem to work. Do you have to specify exactly what is coming in?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do it for whatever subdomain was being requested, try the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{HTTP_HOST}
</IfModule>
```

If you need something more advanced, use mod_rewrite to set an environment variable and then refer to it using `%{variable_name}e`